# How to find the closest value and return the value of the other column?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

```r
dfdf<-data.frame(a= c(80,90,100,110,120),
b= c(500,400,300,200,100))
index= 102
```

How to find the closest value to 102 in column a and return the value of the same row in column b?

expected output:
300

```r
#attempt 1
index2<-min(abs(dfdf$a- index))
dfdf$b[dfdf$a- index==index2] # error sometimes positive values ​​and other times the value is negative

##output:
>numeric(0)
```

Comment: do you want to fill the whole column with the identified nearest number? If yes, what happens when you have two nearest numbers?

Comment: No, I just want to return the value of column "b" which is on the same line as the value of column "a" which is closer to 102.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or following what you tried already:

```
dfdf$b[which.min(abs(index - dfdf$a))]
# [1] 300
```

As a side note (not sure what your outcome should be if there are two matches):

```
dfdf<-data.frame(a= c(80,90,105,105,120),
                 b= c(500,400,300,200,100))
index= 105


dfdf$b[which.min(abs(index - dfdf$a))]
# [1] 300

dfdf[findInterval(index, dfdf$a),"b"]
# [1] 200
```

One more fun example:

```
dfdf<-data.frame(a= c(80,90,100,105,120),
                 b= c(500,400,300,200,100))
index= 95

dfdf$b[which.min(abs(index - dfdf$a))]
# [1] 400

dfdf[findInterval(index, dfdf$a),"b"]
# [1] 400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findInterval` which returns index of nearest value;

```
dfdf[findInterval(102, dfdf$a),"b"]

 # [1] 300
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, if the difference between two obs is the same and it is non-zero ```findinterval``` takes the first one, whereas if it is zero it chooses the second one. Why is this? (I hope there isnt anything silly I have overlooked)

Comment: @desval If you run `?findInterval` it explains how to control that behavior as desired using optional arguments `rightmost.closed` and `all.inside`.